# How can I replace the first lines of a text file with the new input in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am doing a little program in order to learn and understand Java.
The user should be able to create a project, edit it later and add members working on it. 
All of this should be inserted into a textfile (through the console) with Java.
I managed to create it and add members to it, but the editing of it just does not work.

For the editing it should delete the first seven lines and overwrite it with the new input.
The rest of the text file should not change.

My tries all ended up that the whole file was overwritten with the new input.

Not sure if it makes a difference that the whole content is in one string and not seven individual ones.

```
File file = new File("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt");
    String content = ("ID: " + (id) + LINE_SEPARATOR + "Projektname: " + (projektname) + 
    LINE_SEPARATOR + "Beschreibung der Projektaktivitäten: " + (beschreibung) + LINE_SEPARATOR + 
    "Beginn: " + (beginn) + LINE_SEPARATOR + "Ende des Projekts: " + (ende) + LINE_SEPARATOR +  "Dauer des Projekts: "
    + (diffDays) + " Tage" +  LINE_SEPARATOR);
```

This topic might be a duplicate(I want open a text file and edit a specific line in java "here">here, but the answers to similiar questions did not bring me to the solution.
For someone who is new to Java its really hard to tell if the code works for me when I change a single line
or that it is completly different.

Thanks a lot of your help,
Chris

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment...

Comment: Nope, an assignment I have set myself to learn Java. I am done with school :)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to replace the first seven lines of a file with new content, and keep the rest of the file the same, there is only one reliable way of doing it.

1. Read the whole file line by line into memory. This can be an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or any other data structure that preserves order.
2. Change the 7 lines (first 7 items of the data structure) to whatever you want the new 7 lines to be.
3. Write out the whole file again, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(out);

String data = "Eazy E";

writer.write(data);
```

Explanation: The FileWriter object opens up a stream between your application and the file.

The BufferedWriter actually does the writing to the file. 
Don't forget to close each stream (good etiquette) with `writer.close()` and `out.close()`.

Hope this answers your question

PS: You have to import these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure is very similar to java properties file. I would suggest you to use the `java.util.Properties` class to read and write your data.

Use the `load` method to read your file. Then use `setProperty` and `getProperty` method to read/write your data. And finally use the `store` method to rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

If it were the *last* seven lines rather than the *first* seven then it would be possible to simply truncate the file at the appropriate point and then add the new content, but since file data is stored in order from top to bottom the only way to replace a segment of data from the top or middle of a file with another segment that may not be the same length is to rewrite everything that follows the target segment as well. You can replace specific bytes in the middle of a file (using RandomAccessFile) but only when the replacement is exactly the same length in bytes as the original.

I would

- open the original file for reading, then read and discard the first seven lines
- open a temporary file for writing and write the new header to it
- copy any remaining content from the reader to the writer
- close both
- rename the temp file to overwrite the original one

This way you don't corrupt the original file if something goes wrong while writing the new version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a certain word or location  use steps for creating and reading file as mentioned here (File, FileReader) and then have an loop (eg; if statement or switch etc) to compare with ouput before writing to output file(eg .write()).